# Bash script with regex not behaving on Ubuntu

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu

I have a Bash script that is working on my OpenSuSE box, but when copied across to my Ubuntu box, is not working. The script reads in from a file. The file has fields separated by white space (tabs and spaces).

```
#!/bin/bash
function test1()
{
    while read LINE
    do
        if [[ $LINE =~ "^$" || $LINE =~ "^#.*" ]] ; then
            continue;
        fi
        set -- $LINE
        local field1=$1
        local field2=$2
    done < test.file
}

test1
```

with test.file containing:

```
# Field1Header    Field2Header
abcdef            A-2
ghijkl            B-3
```

There seem to be two problems:

(1) $field2, the one with the hyphen, is blank

(2) The regex to strip out the blank lines and lines that start with # is not working

Anyone know what's wrong? As I said, it works fine on OpenSuSE.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Are you actually running it in bash?  On Ubuntu, /bin/sh is not bash.

Comment: Hi. At the top of the file I have "#!/bin/bash". I'll edit my post to that effect.

Comment: `local` doesn't work outside a function.

Comment: it's in a function - above is a snippet

Comment: What versions of Bash are you using on the two systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, as of bash 3.2 the regular expression should not be quoted. So this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE
do
    if [[ $LINE =~ ^$ || $LINE =~ ^#.* ]] ; then
        continue;
    fi
    set -- $LINE
    local field1=$1
    local field2=$2
done < test.file
```

Edit: you should probably use Jo So's answer as it's definitely cleaner. But I was explaining why the regex fails and the reason behind the different behavior between OpenSuse and Ubuntu(different version of bash, very probably)

Comment: OMG, it is true! (Quoting `man bash`:  `Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed  on  the words  between  the [[ and ]];`) Bash is an ugly pile of crap, I would never use such ugly extensions!

Answer (score 3):

1. Quoting is wrong, that probably accounts for the regex failing.
2. No need to use bashisms.
3. No need to use `set`

Try

```
while read field1 field2 dummy
do
    if ! test "${field1%%#*}"
    then
        continue
    fi
    # do stuff here
done
```

**EDIT**: The obvious version using `set`

```
while read -r line
do
    if ! test "${line%%#*}"
    then
        continue
    fi
    set -- $line
    do_stuff_with "$@"
done
```

Comment: Thank you. I have to admit I don't understand the %% syntax. Also, the reason I use set is because I don't have a fixed number of fields on a line; I know my post suggested I do, but I was just trying to simplify as must as possible.

Comment: So XyProblem strikes back. Regarding the %% syntax (that means "remove largest suffix glob-matching `#*`"), it's POSIX as opposed to the nasty regex bashisms. Look for "Parameter Expansion"

Answer (score -2):

On my ubuntu there is no expresion like "=~" for `test` command. Just use this one:

```
if [[ $LINE = "" || ${LINE:0:1} = "#" ]] ; then
    continue;
fi
```

Comment: `=~` is a Bash operator for regex matching. If you have Bash, then you have it. The `test` command (or the equivalent `[`) don't support it, but the double square bracket form does.